# Issues with Magento (ZEND MAIL + Customers do not receive the Order Confirmation)

Tags: shipment, shipment-tracking, send-mail, order-confirmation, zend

I'm new here!
I sign up to this forum because I have encountered some problems with my Magento **(version: 1.8.1.0)**.

1. When a customer ends the checkout by clicking on "Effettua Ordine" ("place an order", in English) I receive the order (in fact, I can see it showed on my backend) but the customer does not, **he doesn't receive an order confirmation e-mail**. Previously, customers received that e-mail and then they were redirected on a landing page named "Checkout Success", which advised about the order confirmation. So, what did happen?
2. When I'm into the backend (path: SALES -> Orders -> a specific order I need to ship -> SHIP ) and I try to insert the Tracking Number, then by clicking on "Submit Shipment" I receive a fatal error: **"Class 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail' not found in /home/MYSITE-7public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php on line 1176"**.

I've already opened a ticket with my Hosting, asking for some help. Below, I copy-paste our conversation:

> **HOSTING:** Hello, It looks like the code was modified, you may have modified it while trying to fix the original problem in
> public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php. I have gone through it and reviewed
> associated logs but don't see any other server side issues. You should
> check recent changes/updates on site and also try reverting back them.
> This is because I believe it was working before. Consulting with
> developer should also help. Upon researching online it looks like the
> default shouldn't be changed and for zend mail transport specifically,
> an include should be in place instead of 'transport'.
> #require_once 'Zend/Mail/Transport/Sendmail.php'; $transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail();
>
> **ME:** Thanks for your help. By the way, I never modified the code so how it can be? Is it possible that during a  TCH server update, a part
> of the code is been modified? And can you revert it for me?  I had no
> problems 'til 28th June, but then on Monday 29th since the morning
> (UTC+1 hour) I had those problems I have written before. In the last
> six months I (as well as the webmaster or developer) never did
> anything about the code, and never installed any adding mods, patch,
> or whatever. The only "actions" made on the website were about adding
> products and receiving and fulfill orders so what change could have
> modified the code causing these errors?
>
> **HOSTING:** First of all we don't manage or monitor your site code and server upgrades/server softwares updates has nothing to do with
> your site's internal codes. It doesn't affect to any of your site
> data. Let me know what server update you are referring to. All I can
> see that the first was logged on the same date and most probably the
> same time you mentioned. If time doesn't match that that could be only
> because of different time zones but date looks same. I would suggest
> you check this with someone else who has access and works/manage your
> site/cart. [28-Jun-2020 09:58:23 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Call to a
> member function validate() on a non-object in
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Standard.php
> on line 137 [28-Jun-2020 12:05:18 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Class
> 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail' not found in
> /home/MYSITE/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php on line 1176*

So in the end, does anyone can help me to fix these two issues with Magento and Zend Mail?

Thank you in advance,

Danilo
(CimaStore)